# Admob performance gap on iOS

Tags: ios, admob

I developed a game using Sprite Kit and on top of the game I added an AdMob banner view using the latest GoogleAds SDK.

However after I added the banner the game started to lag.
Is there something I can do about?

When I use iAd there is no lags (almost) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob should not cause lag but it could be because you are loading your GADRequest during gameplay, you should do it when your game is not as intensive or while its loading. Also are you showing your ads during gameplay cause that can sometimes cause lag as well